# Syntax error on token ";" - really unexpected

Tags: java

I got the problem with the following error:

Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete EnumBody

```
public enum ImpNoise {
  INSTANCE;

   private int p[] = new int[512];


   for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {

   }

}
```

I stripped the whole class down to the bare minimum as you can see above.
I figured out that the for loop is causing the problem.
But i really don't get it, it looks ok right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place code in a code block. Only initialisers for fields can avoid this.

What you may have intended was

```
public enum ImpNoise {
   INSTANCE;

   private final int[] p = new int[512];

   // either
   {
       for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {

       }
   }
   // or
   private ImpNoise() {
       for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {

       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't just put a `for` statement (or any other statement, for that matter) in the [class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classdecl.html) body, outside of a [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html), a [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html), or a code [block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html). If you want your code to run when the class is created, put it in the constructor:

```
public enum ImpNoise {
  INSTANCE;

  private int p[] = new int[512];

  private ImpNoise() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {

    }
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [Declaring Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classdecl.html)
- [Providing Constructors to your Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)
- [Defining Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Comment: is it possible to have a method called on the creation of the instance?

Comment: @clankill3r: Yes, put the required code in the constructor. Also note that since `ImpNoise` is an enum, the constructor will only run once.

Answer (score 1):

The loop should belong to a method and it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put your `for` loop inside a method or constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Java enums are full fledged classes they allow you to write methods, implement interface etc. But surely not write code like this :)

You can read more on Enums [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html)